# Symfony: security.firewalls.main.form_login.default_target_path is being ignored

Tags: symfony, redirect

I am creating my first application in Symfony 5, I created the auth system using make command, and I am trying to make my app to redirect to /home when the user logs in but I have been unable.

I have read I have to set the parameter `security.firewalls.main.form_login.default_target_path` in the security.yaml

https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login.html#redirecting-after-success

I know this file is being read because if I intentionally misspell it the application throws an error, but it does not matter what I put on that field, after login I always get redirected to root page /

Why is this happening? How can I redirect users to `home` route after login?

As aditional info:

- Controller's login action has the default code as it gets generated.
- `home` route exists and points to `/home`

This is the content of my security.yaml:

```yaml
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: auto

    providers:
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: username
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            anonymous: true
            lazy: true
            provider: app_user_provider
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\AppAuthenticator
            logout:
                path: app_logout

            form_login:
                default_target_path:  home

    access_control:
        - { path: '^/proyecto', roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

Comment: You may be confusing two different authentication approaches.  Typically you would use either a guard authenticator or form_login.  Not both.  Did you follow [How to build a login form](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html) and use bin/console make:auth?  Basically, check your AppAuthenticator::onAuthenticationSuccess method and add your redirect code there.  And yes the security system is very confusing.

Comment: Thank you man, Yes, I found the path explicitly declared on `AppAuthenticator::onAuthenticationSuccess` method. That was the problem

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Cerad, I found out I was mixing up two different authentication aproaches.

I had to check onAuthenticationSuccess method on AppAuthenticator class. There I had the explicit redirection to `/`

In that method I can define the redirection path